# Cryastl Reports is not recognizing that a new parameter has been added to the report's stored proc

Tags: stored-procedures, crystal-reports

i have added another input parameter to a stored proc used by a crystal report.  i've had our dba recompile the stp to be sure that the new parameter is cached and "really there".

i cannot get my crystal report to recognize the new parameter -- i've tried verifying database and using the Set Datasource Location/Update to re-select the stp.

i'm using cr11 against a 2005 sql server db.

any other suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

right click stored procedure click verify database then Press Cancel Button that will do the trick...^^

Answer (score 2):

I'd try these in order:

1) verify the database, then test for new parameter
2) check using sql server management studio that the parameter is really there.
3) close crystal reports and reopen & verify database, then test for new parameter
4) close crystal reports remove data source, add data source back, and reopen crystal & verify database, then test for new parameter
5) reboot and then try #3

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing and adding the data source?

Usually verify DB works, but have had a couple cases where I had you remove and add again.